# Haskell: Applicative over tuples

Tags: haskell

I have a problem. I have a datatype Thing thats essentially a big record of Maybe Doubles or Maybe Texts. I want to create a datatype that can capture the idea of running computations on it even though some fields may be Nothing.

```
data Computation a b = Computation
    { getInputs :: Thing -> a
      computation :: a -> b
      modifyThing :: b -> Thing -> Thing
    }
```

Based on the output b, which will most likely correspond to some field in Thing, I want to create a new Thing.

```
modifyThing :: b -> Thing -> Thing
```

The computation from Thing to Maybe b can be split up into two parts, loading the variables and a computation that just accepts numbers or texts.

```
getInputs :: Thing -> a

computation :: a -> b
```

The above is almost what I want. In this case, a would be (Maybe a1, Maybe a2..) and so on. This means that in "computation" and getInputs
I have to do something like

```
getInputs t = \t -> ( getProp1 t , getProp2 t)

computation = \(m_a1, m_a2) -> do
    a1 <- m_a1
    a2 <- m_a2
    return $ a1 + a2
```

I would much rather have computation just look like

```
exampleComp a1 a2 = a1 + a2
```

and then do something like

```
runComputation :: Thing -> Computation -> b
runComputation thing comp = magic (computation comp) ((getInputs comp) thing)
  where magic = ???
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do go from

```
(Maybe a1, Maybe a2, ... , Maybe a_n)
```

to

```
a1 -> a2 -> ... -> a_n
```

If any of the Maybe's are Nothing then just return Nothing. I can do

```
pure computation <*> m_a1 <*> m_a2 <*> m_a3
```

but how can I write magic to work for any sort of tuple?

P.S.

I was thinking about writing computation as

```
computation :: Thing -> b
```

and doing away with getInputs, but it seems it would be much more unweildy
for me to test and play with. That's why I'm trying to go with the approach I have described above. Do you think this is a good idea what I have done?

**edited**

While not a solution to the particular question I asked, but to the intent of what I was trying to do, I decided that doing

```
data Computation = Computation
    { getInputs :: Thing -> Maybe a
    , computation :: a -> b
    , modifyThing :: b -> Thing -> Thing
    }
```

would be the best way to go forward. This way I don't have to worry about the tuples.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a list of maybe's?

Comment: @Guvante One drawback of lists is that they are homogeneous -- e.g. one wouldn't be able to pick out both a `Double`-y typed field and an `Int`-y typed field at the same time.

Comment: @user3550758 If you find a solution, the StackOverflow way is to write it up as an answer, not include it in an edit to the question. I encourage you to split your "edit" out into its own entity -- and even accept it if it is the best answer you get. (This is considered perfectly polite and even desirable here.)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I don't know how to do go from
>
> ```
> (Maybe a1, Maybe a2, ... , Maybe a_n)
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> a1 -> a2 -> ... -> a_n
> ```

Looks similar-ish to `uncurry`, which takes an ordinary function and makes a version that takes a tuple instead of multiple arguments.

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f (a, b) = f a b
```

This particular example:

```
computation = \(m_a1, m_a2) -> do
    a1 <- m_a1
    a2 <- m_a2
    return $ a1 + a2
```

can be done with Applicative like so

```
computation (m_a1, m_a2) = (+) <$> m_a1 <*> m_a2
```

But you can abstract this to something like `uncurry` like this:

```
uncurryA :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> (f a, f b) -> f c
uncurryA f (a, b) = f <$> a <*> b
```

Allowing `computation` to be defined like so:

```
computation a_b = uncurryA (+) a_b
```

Comment: `uncurry` only works with 2-argument functions, though. You might do some sort of recursive uncurrying (since `uncurry . uncurry`, for example, can turn `a -> a -> a -> b` into `((a, a), a) -> b`), but you'd still have to figure out how to flatten the resulting nested tuple.

Comment: (Or more accurately, `uncurry` only handles the first two arguments at a time, which leads to the nested tuple if `uncurry` is used multiple times successively.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the benefit of using a `Computation` instead of a `Thing -> Thing`, but you should be able to define the functions in question fairly easily. First of all, your example function, `computation`, can be rewritten in a slightly more convenient form. (You should actually call it something else, since the name `computation` is already taken by your record accesor).

```
exampleComp :: Num a => (Maybe a, Maybe a) -> Maybe a
exampleComp (a1, a2) = liftA2 (+) a1 a2
```

It still isn't quite as convenient as plain addition, but it comes close. Your `runComputation` function is also pretty simple, since it really just comes down to composing the three components of your `Computation` type.

```
runComputation :: Thing -> Computation -> Thing
runComputation thing (Computation ins comp modify) = modify (comp $ ins thing) thing
```

Or, written with record accessors, it looks like this.

```
runComputation thing comp = modifyThing comp 
                            (computation comp $ getInputs comp thing) 
                            thing
```

Basically, this function extracts the appropriate data using `getInputs`, passes that data to `computation` to get a new set of data, then passes *that* to `modifyThing` to actually modify the object.

Without more information about exactly what you plan to do with your datatype, it's hard to say which method you should use. Personally, I can't see any reason to seperate `computation` and `modifyThing`, but I can't really see any reason to use `Computation` in the first place, either. Regardless, that's more a question for CodeReview than it is for StackOverflow.